# Getting latest value from joined table

Tags: sql-server, join, getlatest

I have 2 tables joined by a mapping table
I want to get the the intensity from the last Tap.

```
With IssuesCTE AS
(
Select * from Issues
), 
TapsCTE AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        MapIssueTaps.IssueId,
        SD.Id,
        SD.Intensity,
        SD.Notes,
        Row_Number() OVER 
        (
        PARTITION BY MapIssueTaps.IssueId ORDER BY SD.CreatedOn DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM Taps SD
join MapIssueTaps on MapIssueTaps.TapId=SD.Id 
)
Select IssuesCTE.*,TapsCTE.* from IssuesCTE,TapsCTE
join MapIssueTaps on MapIssueTaps.TapId = TapsCTE.Id
--where RowNumber=1
```

Here is all the data:

```
UserId  Id  Name    Intensity   CreatedOn   UpdatedOn   Description IssueId Id  Intensity   Notes   RowNumber
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    1   c   2   2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 cx  1   3   8   dd  1
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    8   d   5   2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 d   1   3   8   dd  1
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    1   c   2   2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 cx  1   2   1   xzc 2
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    8   d   5   2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 d   1   2   1   xzc 2
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    1   c   2   2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 cx  1   1   8   ss  3
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    8   d   5   2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 d   1   1   8   ss  3
```

I would like this:

```
UserId  Id  Name    Intensity   CreatedOn   UpdatedOn   Description IssueId Id  Intensity   Notes   RowNumber
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    1   c   2   2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 cx  1   3   8   dd  1
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0    8   d   5   2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 d   1   3   null    dd  1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Uncomment out `where RowNumber=1`.  That should do the trick.

Comment: I commented that out so I could see all the rows in the dump in the bottom output is the commented out version but the currentintensity was the same in both cases but its different in the data, basically I want to return a value from the the associated taps table with latestdate but it has to be efficient

Comment: I still don't get the issue.  You seem to want the third column from the end to be `null` instead of `8`.  Is that the issue?

Comment: there are 2 issues id 1 and 8  ... there are 3 taps id 1,2,3 and in the maps table there is mapping issueid,tapid 1,1 1,2 1,3 so the second issues doesn't have any taps map but the query bring back the same max value as it did for the first row ... the second row hasn't got any taps data mapped ... I would put all the data here but these  message boxes are really small

Comment: With IssuesCTE AS
(
Select * from Issues
), 
TapsCTE AS 
( 
  SELECT 
        MapIssueTaps.IssueId,
        Tapstab.Id,
        Tapstab.Intensity,
        Tapstab.Notes,
        Row_Number() OVER 
        (
        PARTITION BY MapIssueTaps.IssueId ORDER BY Tapstab.CreatedOn DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM Taps Tapstab
join MapIssueTaps on MapIssueTaps.TapId=Tapstab.Id 
)
Select IssuesCTE.*,TapsCTE.* from IssuesCTE
join TapsCTE on IssuesCTE.id = TapsCTE.IssueId
where RowNumber=1

Comment: A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0 1 c 2 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 cx 1 4 7 dds 1
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0 8 d 5 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 d 8 5 4 2nd issue 1 works !!! only one thing now is how to make a left outer join the data so that I get Issues that don't have a tap and get null for the tap data

Comment: cracked it properly ... With IssuesCTE AS
(
Select * from Issues
), 
TapsCTE AS 
( 
  SELECT 
        Issues.Id as IssueId,
        Tapstab.Id,
        Tapstab.Intensity,
        Tapstab.Notes,
        Row_Number() OVER 
        (
        PARTITION BY IssueId ORDER BY Tapstab.CreatedOn DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM Taps Tapstab
join MapIssueTaps on MapIssueTaps.TapId=Tapstab.Id 
right outer join Issues on MapIssueTaps.IssueId = Issues.Id
)
Select IssuesCTE.*,TapsCTE.* from IssuesCTE
join TapsCTE on IssuesCTE.id = TapsCTE.IssueId
where RowNumber=1

Comment: A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0 9 anotherissue 10 2014-02-04 20:59:17.423 2014-02-04 20:59:17.423 ai 9 NULL NULL NULL 1
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0 1 c 2 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 2014-02-02 03:53:33.200 cx 1 4 7 dds 1
A291B6F4-866D-4EFA-9522-7AA45710C7E0 8 d 5 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 2014-02-03 22:16:24.157 d 8 5 4 2nd issue 1 boom ... :)